# How to access a program's main loop in .NET (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, timer

This one is a little hard to explain, and I hope I explain it correctly.

I am trying to access the main application's loop of a .NET program.  The reason why I must do this, is because I must access the loop of the main program's thread, so that I can *pause* the entire application with a breakpoint, or sleep function.

I know that the code ***Application.Run(Form)*** is how to execute a form, but what can I do in order to get access to that form's main program loop?  I am trying to avoid using the Timer event handlers for this reason:  When I put *sleep* functions in the Timer event handlers, the program's animation continues to run in the background (is this because the Timer event handlers are a separate thread?).  But I need the program to come to a complete halt, like it is frozen in time.  The goal is to step edit through the loop, and have the program's animation execute frame by frame, only as I step edit through the main program's loop.

I know this sounds strange, but this is the functionality I require.

Thanks everyone!

===============================================================

**Edit:  A better explanation from a technical point of view.**

===============================================================

In C, the main window entry point is:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPreInst,LPSTR lpszCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
```

In this function, we have a message loop code, such as:

```
while(GetMessage(&lpMsg,NULL,0,0))
    {   TranslateMessage(&lpMsg);
        DispatchMessage(&lpMsg);
    }
```

Within that function, another function called "CreateWindow" creates the main window, then jumps to a Callback function called "WndProc" which is the equivalent of event handlers in .NET.  The event handler for the timer function is:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT messg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    case WM_TIMER:          
        CODE:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd,messg,wParam,lParam);
```

My goal is to get access to the message loop, in this case, the while loop that executes the WM_TIMER case, of the main entry point in .NET, the same way you do in C.

Here is a reference link to the program flow I described above:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can't you send the main form via constructor or use a static variable ?

Comment: Can't you just used `Thread.Sleep(xxx)`? Yes - timer `Elapsed` event runs on separate thread

Comment: Whether or not a timer executes on a separate thread depends on the timer. Windows forms timers run on the UI thread.

Comment: Why do you require this functionality?

Comment: Thread.Sleep(xxx) only pauses the current thread, not the main thread.  For example, windows messages will still continue to occur.  I need to access the main thread due to an anomaly with some code I am working with.  Basically, I need to simulate the way a C main program timer event works.

Answer (score -1):

Application.Run starts the application.
The 'Application' object holds the form and manages the dispatcher object (which is essentially the 'message loop' for the form. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application(v=vs.110).aspx .
Read about the Dispatcher property.

Note: Windows also has an OS level 'message loop'.

Comment: The link provided here doesn't help explain how to access a timer event on the main thread though.